# ReactJS: State does not update upon onChange when initial state is from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Form Input and I have my value set to the initial state which is from my props. Now I have a handleChange function and when I try to type in my Form Input it does trigger the onChange but the value does not change at all.

```
  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
    console.log('handle change', this.state.firstName)
  }
```

`console.log` returns what the initial state is, even though I type on my keyboard, it still returns the initial state.
this is my `handleChange()`

while this is my initial state:

```
    this.state = {
      firstName: this.props.profiles.selectedProfile.first_name
    }
```

and this is my Input

```
<Form.Input 
label="First Name"
value={this.state.firstName}
placeholder="Jose"
onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

this works when I only have an empty string declared on my state but now that my initial state is from my props, it does not work.

Comment: do you mind logging the `e.target.name` in the `handleChange` function.
also, are you binding this `handleChange` in the constructor? also try: `firstName: this.props.profiles.selectedProfile.first_name || ''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying `[e.target.name]: e.target.value`, or `name = value` but you are not sending name field.

This code should fix the issue.

```
<Form.Input 
label="First Name"
name='firstName'
value={this.state.firstName}
placeholder="Jose"
onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Also you need to bind `handleChange` to this in constructor which I assume you are not doing.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }
```

`console.log('handle change', this.state.firstName)` will not give you the latest state value, because setState is asynchronous, if you want to get latest state value, use callback of setState.

Comment: yes I have forgotten the name!!! but I did bind it in the constructor. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the state in componentDidMount using this.setState

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({firstName : this.props.profiles.selectedProfile.first_name});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because props are [immutable](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only) on React.

If you asign a props to a state, that state will be immutable too, because the value of the state is immutable value.

To well understand, I will simulate it:

```
var a = 0;
var b;
a = b;
// it means b = a too
```

If you change `b`, `a` will be changed as well.

**So the value of the state you assign is immutable value, the state will become immutable.**

I hope it helps you to understand it.
For more information: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html